# How to get data from database using switch case?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Below is the sample code:

```
function fill_product(i){
var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
form1.product.options.length=0;
switch(i)
{   

case 0:
form1.product.options[0] =new  Option('**get data from database, like the select                query**');
form1.product.options[1] =new  Option('**get data from database, like the select     query**');

break;

case 1:
form1.product.options[0] =new  Option('**get data from database, like the select     query**',''); 
form1.product.options[1] =new  Option('**get data from database, like the select     query**');
form1.product.options[2] =new  Option('**get data from database, like the select quer**y');

break;
```

On the above code - how can I query and select data from my database?

Comment: That's not PHP, that's Javascript.

Comment: If you want to call PHP from Javascript, you have to use AJAX. You should do an AJAX call to get all the options, and then loop over the result to build the menu.

Comment: Do you have a way set up to connect to your database? You can connect, get the data from mysql and print out the values with php at page display time... Or later using AJAX, depending  on what your aim is exactly.

Comment: Okay Barmar thanks, i will try to query and printing the vaulues first before using AJAX

Comment: form1.product.options[2] =new  Option('$data'); will be my query will be something like that after i put the data on a variable???